# Underbrace problem

Tags: braces

I have some problem to make the Underbrace partly for the equation like the picture shows. The unique part is the "b" is used twice.

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: What is the expected output? Try to explain it a little better. **EDIT:** I mean, if we achieve that “*b* is used twice”, both underbraces will obviously collide. Do you want one under, and other over? And then, on the top, the bigger one?

Comment: As your reader, I'd be confused by this...

Comment: @Jubobs ,my bad,Eglish is not my first language. I didn't explain it in a proper way. I would like to say that the first under-brace is for "a+b" and the second under-brace is for "b+c" but there is only one "b" appeared in the equation. And usually I use \underbrace{a+b}_\text{bla bla} for the first under-brace. However, the b is already used buy the first under-brace so \underbrace{b?+c}_\text{bla bla} is really a problem for me

Comment: No no `:)` I understand what output you want to achieve. I'm just saying I have a problem with the output itself: whether  `b` belongs to one, both or none of the the underbraces is not immediately obvious to me, and it may not be to your readers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can underbrace “a+(nothing)”, print a zero width “b” and again underbrace “(nothing)+c”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
\overbrace{
  \underbrace{a+{}}_\text{text}
  \mathclap{b}
  \underbrace{{}+c}_\text{text}
}^{\text{text}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user3004698 It would require some more work in case the symbol in the middle is wider. Just add to your question in case you need some adjustments.